# Saving class instances into a database in Java

Tags: java, sql, database

I want to learn how to execute basic SQL commands from a Java application. I have been searching for hours and all i can see are stuff to connect to a database. Can anyone provide a sample code to save instances of a simple class containing two fields, a Name(String) and Id(Int) in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JDBC API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) is a Java API that can access any kind of tabular data, especially data stored in a Relational Database.

The following simple code fragment gives a simple example of these three steps:

```
public void connectToAndQueryDatabase(String username, String password) {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",
                         username,
                         password);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table1");

    while (rs.next()) {
        int x = rs.getInt("a");
        String s = rs.getString("b");
        float f = rs.getFloat("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: can I execute any SQL command in stmt.executeQuery ?

Comment: @user2262955 : You can check the apis and you have to correct driver.

Comment: @user2262955 no, not any. You must execute a query with `executeQuery()`. You must use `executeUpdate()` to execute an update.

Comment: According to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html, stmt.execute("SQL statment") can execute any sql statment.